# input submit on enter hit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want my input action on enter key is pressed, but my code won't work.

**html :**

```
<div>
    <div class="chat" data-active="1">
        <section class="chat_info">
            <span class="name">
            </span>
            <div class="options">
                <div class="minimize">_</div>
                <div class="exit">X</div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <section class="conversation">
        </section>
        <section class="message">
            <input type="text" id="abc" size="10">
        </section>    
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my script, but it doesnt work when hitting enter:

```
$(document).on("keypress", ".message input", function(event){
    var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);

    if(keycode === 13) {
        alert();                
    }
});
```

Comment: [The issue is not in the code you've shown](http://jsfiddle.net/XH24P/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's probably because you don't have the jQuery library properly installed. I copy-pasted your exact code into [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.com) and selected their jQuery 1.9.1... it works. i.e. your code is not the problem.

Try pasting this into your <head></head>

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
```

Should work.

Answer (score 0):

I use this, works for sure:

```
$('.message input').bind('keypress', function(e) {
    var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
    if(code == 13) {   //Enter keycode
        alert();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

is the way i allways do for this:

```
$('#abc').keypress(function(event){
var keycode = (event.keyCode ? event.keyCode : event.which);
if(keycode == '13'){
    alert('You pressed a "enter" key in textbox');  
}
});
```

http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/12/24/jquery-detect-if-enter-key-is-pressed/